# Difference between Talend Open Studio for Data Integration and Talend Open Studio for Big Data

Tags: business-intelligence, talend

I'm confused by the different products that Talend offer.

It seems that `Talend Open Studio for Data Integration` and `Talend Open Studio for Big Data` are the same product but just with different components installed by default. Is that right? If I use Talend Open Studio for Data Integration and download the components I need from Talend Exchange (e.g. for Google BigQuery), is it effectively the same product?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Aside from the different connectors they differ on one key point, the code base they generate.

Talend Open Studio for Data Integration generates Java code while the Talend Open Studio for Big Data can generate map reduce code as well as Java code.

See [here](https://help.talend.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=18175254) for an example of Talend's Big Data offering showing how to generate map reduce code jobs.

Comment: +1; another big difference, however, is the lack of metadata repository in TOS-BD. This because the latter is released under Apache Common License, while Talend Open Studio for Data Integration is released under LGPL. The metadata repository found in TOS for DI was incompatible with Apache License and so it was removed starting from release 4.1

Answer (score 4):

It's not only about components :

From : http://www.talend.com/products/data-integration

> Features : Job Designer, Job Designer, 450+ Connectors, Versioning

From : http://www.talend.com/products/big-data

> Features : Job Designer, Components for HDFS, HBase, HCatalog, Hive,
>   Pig, Sqoop, Hadoop Job Scheduler, NoSQL Support

*I'm not sure, but I don't think that official components can be found at Talend's exchange website. There you will only find community contributed components.*

Comment: No, they generate code in a different way. TOS cannot generate M/R code, while BD could.

Answer (score 2):

In Talend Open Studio for Data Integration you can create Standard Job (means directly you can use DI component and in the back side java code will be generated).

But Talend Open Studio for Big Data you have option to create map/reduce job (means in the back side map/reduce code [actually java map/reduce] code will be generated). In the map/reduce job all component run both map and reduce task in the talend server. Like in tmap component you can see map and reduce task bar below the component when its executed.

Answer (score 1):

Talend has different Open Studio products for different requirements.

Talend OS for Data Integration - Caters to Data Integration/ETL requirements. This will not have Big Data specific components.

Talend OS for Big Data- Caters to Big Data requirements. You can connect to Hadoop,Hive and other Big Data components. Apart from generating Java code this can also generate map reduce code.

You also have Talend OS for ESB, MDM & Data Quality which cater to different requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Talend does not differentiate between connectors.Spark is the differentator between TOS and licensed version.

Open studio does not support spark both batch and real-time.